# Error in table creation

Tags: mysql

I got the below error after pasting the below MySQL command on MySQL terminal.This code I got it from my project's production environment.I want to update the local db according to the production env's db.

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE `cityguide_pointofinterest` (
    ->   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ->   `name` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `vip` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
    ->   `description` longtext COLLATE utf8_danish_ci NOT NULL,
    ->   `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `email` varchar(254) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci,
    ->   `latitude` double NOT NULL,
    ->   `longitude` double NOT NULL,
    ->   `phone` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci,
    ->   `place` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   `website` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci,
    ->   `date_created` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    ->   `date_modified` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
    ->   `views` int(11) NOT NULL,
    ->   `picture_1` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci,
    ->   `picture_2` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci,
    ->   `picture_3` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci,
    ->   `order_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_danish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    ->   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ->   KEY `cityguide_pointofi_category_id_8ab78aba_fk_cityguide_category_id` (`category_id`),
    ->   CONSTRAINT `cityguide_pointofi_category_id_8ab78aba_fk_cityguide_category_id` FOREIGN KEY (`category_id`) REFERENCES `cityguide_category` (`id`)
    -> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=47 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_danish_ci;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
      `date_modified` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
      `views` int(11) NOT NULL' at line 13
    mysql> /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

Comment: What purpose does serve the `datetime(6)` in your query? I mean, why 6?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it would run replacing all the `datetime(6)` by `datetime`

Comment: so it should be `datetime`?

Comment: Yeah I think so. I mean I always used it like that and I don't think you can set a length here. And even if you could, I don't see what it would change since the `datetime` format in MySQL is already constrained in size.

Comment: But wait, it actually runs in my DB console as it is...

Comment: ya, it works. But I donno why doing the table backup gives datetime(6)?

Comment: I checked the doc, it's actually the fractional precision of the seconds: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html

Comment: is there any big difference between `datetime` and `datetime(6)`?

Comment: `datetime` by default is equivalent to `datetime(0)`, it's less precise than `datetime(6)` but `datetime(6)` takes 3 more bytes per SQL row because of the additional precision. According to the doc.

Comment: Then how I write query of field type datetime(6)?

Comment: It's just a matter of formatting your date with the milliseconds precision. I don't know the writing format of that much precision but I'm pretty confident you can find it in the doc without too much trouble. Thanks for the post though, TIL that datetime could be parametrized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MYSQL version is 5.5 or below i think.

**MySQL 5.7** has fractional seconds support for TIME, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP values, with up to microseconds (6 digits) precision:

> To define a column that includes a fractional seconds part, use the
>   syntax type_name(fsp), where type_name is TIME, DATETIME, or
>   TIMESTAMP, and fsp is the fractional seconds precision. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (t TIME(3), dt DATETIME(6));
```

The fsp value, if given, must be in the range 0 to 6. A value of 0 signifies that there is no fractional part. If omitted, the default precision is 0. (This differs from the standard SQL default of 6, for compatibility with previous MySQL versions.)

**[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5731f)**